# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I doing a Batch File and Got the error please help me.

The Error --

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT OPTION' at line 1
```

MySQL Script

```
CREATE USER 'a4db'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '0987654321'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'a4db'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '0987654321' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I'm want to create the new user for remote the Sql Databases from client PC. If I copy the script to the workbench or to cmd it will run correctly and no error.

Please help me solve this error.

Comment: whats the version of your mysql ?

Comment: i using version 5.5

Comment: in workbench and cmd, works correctly..  so where is this error ?

Comment: the error happen when i run this script with batch file.. i now create the patch file for my client sql..

Answer (score 0):

Add `*.*` between `ON` and `TO` ,the first `*` is your database name,and the second `*` is the table name. `*.*` means all database.all tables. For example, if you want this user just have the right to operate table 'test' in the database 'db',you may write like this `db.test`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'a4db'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '0987654321' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I have added the *.* between ON and TO, but it still fail

Comment: @M.Zahir  Run the `CREATE USER` and excute `use mysql; select Host,Password,User from user;` what did you get? Can you find the user you created?

Comment: by using MySQL I can create the user..but I put this script into the batch file and it has the error